# Login to facebook with Indy

Tags: facebook, delphi, post, indy

I would like to login to my facebook account with Indy. The version is 9.00.10 and I use OpenSSL with TIDHTTP and assigned a cookie manager to it. Everything works fine (I can send a POST request a GET, etc.)

I sniffed the actual login to facebook and I have the following information:

- UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
- There are several POST parameters:

  - lsd = I have no idea what that is.
  - email = The actual facebook username/email.
  - pass = The password (unencrypted) --> I was shocked to see in clear text.
  - default_persistent = (0 or 1) for "keep me logged in"
  - timezone = Timezone code.
  - lgnrnd = I have no idea what that is.
  - lgnjs = I have no idea what that is.
  - locale = GEOIP location (e.x. en_US)

The post is made on https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1. However when I try to login it returns that I have entered an incorrect eMail. I'm sure I used the right eMail and Password.

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TEST : STRING;
  lParamList: TStringList;
  i : Integer;
begin
  lParamList := TStringList.Create;
  lparamlist.Add('lsd=AVoBzJ5G');
  lparamlist.Add('email=myeMail%40mysite.com');
  lparamlist.Add('pass=mypass');
  lparamlist.Add('default_persistent=0');
  lparamlist.Add('timezone=240');
  lparamlist.Add('lgnrnd=210302_FeQV');
  lparamlist.Add('lgnjs=1367035381');
  lparamlist.Add('locale=en_US');
  IDHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)';
  Test := IdHTTP1.Get('https://www.facebook.com'); // To get the first cookies.
  for i := 0 to IDHTTP1.CookieManager.CookieCollection.Count - 1 do begin
    ShowMessage(IDHTTP1.CookieManager.CookieCollection.Items[i].CookieText); // Show me the cookies.
  end;
  TEST := IDHTTP1.Post('https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1', lParamList);
  StrToFile ('text.html', test);
  ShellExecute (0, 'open', 'text.html', '', '', SW_SHOW);
end;
```

I used the parameters that I got from LiveHTTPHeaders.
How would I successfully login to facebook with Indy?

EDIT: Tried this with XE2 and Indy 10 but I get the 'incorrect email' error:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IdCookieManager, IdIOHandler,
  IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, DateUtils, ShellAPI, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    IdCookieManager1: TIdCookieManager;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetBetween (Str: String; StrStart : String; StrEnd : String) : String;
var
  iPos    : Integer;
  BackUp  : String;
begin
  result := '';
  iPos := Pos (StrStart, Str);
  if iPos <> 0 then begin
    Delete (Str, 1, iPos + Length (StrStart) - 1);
    iPos := Pos (StrEnd, Str);
    if iPos <> 0 then begin
      result := Copy(Str,1, iPos - 1);
    end;
  end;
end;

function StrToFile(szFilePath:string; dwPosition:DWORD; szInput:string):Boolean;
var
  hFile:      DWORD;
  dwSize:     DWORD;
  dwWritten:  DWORD;
begin
  Result := FALSE;
  hFile := CreateFileW(PWideChar(szFilePath), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
  if hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    dwSize := Length(szInput) * 2;
    if dwSize > 0 then
    begin
      SetFilePointer(hFile, dwPosition, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
      WriteFile(hFile, szInput[1], dwSize, dwWritten, nil);
      if dwWritten = dwSize then
        Result := TRUE;
    end;
    CloseHandle(hFile);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Response      : String;
  lparamList    : TStringList;
begin
  IDHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)';
  try
    Response := IDHTTP1.Get('https://www.facebook.com/');
  except

  end;
  lParamList := TStringList.Create;
  lParamList.Add('lsd='+GetBetween (Response, 'name="lsd" value="', '"'));
  lParamList.Add('eMail=myEmail@mySite.com');
  lParamList.Add('pass=myPassword');
  lParamList.Add('default_persistent'+GetBetween (Response, 'name="default_persistent" value="', '"'));
  lParamList.Add('timezone=240');
  lParamList.Add('lgnrnd='+GetBetween (Response, 'name="lgnrnd" value="', '"'));
  lParamList.Add('lgnjs='+inttostr(DateTimeToUnix(Now)));
  lParamList.Add('locale=en_US');
  IDHTTP1.Request.Referer := 'https://www.facebook.com/';
  try
    Response := IDHTTP1.Post('https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1', lparamList);
  except

  end;
  StrToFile ('test.html', 0, Response);
  ShellExecute (0, 'open', 'test.html', '', '', SW_SHOW);
end;

end.
```

Comment: You have a sniffer.  Sniff the data that Indy is transmitting and compare it to the data that a web browser transmits.

Comment: You can use Fiddler to sniff SSL data, because it acts as a local proxy. It automatically configures WinInet-based apps, including Internet Explorer, to connect through it while it is running. You have to configure other apps manually, including `TIdHTTP` (which has a `ProxyParams` property).

Comment: I use Fiddler to sniff SSL traffic, including `TIdHTTP` traffic, so I know for a fact that it works. Make sure you configure the `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` property to tell `TIdHTTP` to connect to Fiddler and not the HTTPS server directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `hoForceEncodeParams` flag is enabled in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property (which it is by default), then you need to fill the posted `TStringList` with **un**-encoded values.  `TIdHTTP.Post()` will then encode the values for you when transmitting them.

Assuming the `hoForceEncodeParams` flag is enabled, `lparamlist.Add('email=myeMail%40mysite.com');` would be transmitted as `email=myeMail%2540mysite.com` because the `%` character gets encoded as `%25`.  Facebook would decode that as `email=myeMail%40mysite.com` and reject it as an invalid email.

You can either:

1. disable the `hoForceEncodeParams` flag so the `TStringList` values get transmitted as-is.  You would then be responsible for encoding them manually.
2. leave the `hoForceEncodeParams` flag enabled and change `lparamlist.Add('email=myeMail%40mysite.com');` to `lparamlist.Add('email=myeMail@mysite.com');` instead.  `TIdHTTP.Post()` in Indy 9 will then transmit it as `email=myeMail@mysite.com` because Indy 9 does not encode the `@` character.  That may or may not work, depending on how lenient Facebook is.

If you upgrade to Indy 10, `TIdHTTP.Post()` will encode the `@` character as `%40` as expected when the `hoForceEncodeParams` flag is enabled.

Comment: Ok, I considered that and I am a little bit closer now. Although I have the cookie manager, it gives me now that I need to enable cookies.

Comment: BTW. Indy 9 successfully converts the `@` to `%40`

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss: Indy 9's cookie support was not very good. Indy 10's cookie support is much better.  `TIdHTTP.Post()` in Indy 9 does not encode `@`. It uses `TIdURI.ParamsEncode()` for the actual encoding, and `@` is on the list of *safe* characters that `ParamsEncode()` does not encode. But then, I am looking at the code for Indy 9.0.50, and you are using 9.0.10 instead, so maybe 9.0.10 was different.

Comment: Well I'm not sure either about the encoding. The results of my post for facebook shows that the eMailaddress has been successfully added to the facebook login form. It might also be that the facebook server automatically encodes in the right charset. Could you please provide a working sample (Indy 9 or 10) on how to login to facebook successfully? I've been trying the whole day so far and I will go off for now.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss: Again, please use a sniffer to compare Indy's posted data to a webbrowser's posted data and see what is actually different between them.

Comment: I don't see any difference.

Comment: There has to be SOME difference, or else you would not be having this problem. Can you show what you are actually seeing?

Comment: Post an answer, please

Comment: Benjamin poste mal die Lösung :P

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, **the OP's code works just fine with the mobile versions** of Facebook, so just replace www.facebook.com with touch/m.facebook.com.

Now if the OP would also be kind enough to share how he got the full version to work (at least the Cookies not enabled part), I'm sure we'll all be grateful.